# function attempt return false when use username instead of email in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, eloquent

I want to create auth and use username instead of email
when I use email, it returns `true` but when I use username, returns `false`.

This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
redirects them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
to conveniently provide its functionality to your application.

my `LoginController.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use App;
class LoginController extends Controller
{

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{

}
public function login(Request $request){
    //$this->validate($request, [
    //    'name'   => 'required',
    //    'password' => 'required|min:3'
    //]);
    $credentials = [
        'email' => $request->input('username'),
        'password' => $request->input('password'),
    ];
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {

        return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
    }
    else
    {
        $user=new app\User();

        return $user::get();

    }

}
public function logout(){
    Auth::logout();
    return route("login");
}
}
```

this is my model. `User.php`:

```
    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
    public function getAuthIdentifierName()
    {
        return "username";
    }
}
```

`route.php`:

```
    Route::get('/login',function(){
        return view("admin.auth.login");
    })->name('login');

    Route::post('/login',"Auth\LoginController@login");
    Route::get('/logout',"Auth\LoginController@logout")->name('logout');
```

migration code:

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements("id");
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: you can use `name` or `email` for `username`,but you can't use username for  a `email`,email should be a `email`.

Answer (score 0):

Username Customization

By default, Laravel uses the email field for authentication. If you would like to customize this, you may define a username method on your LoginController:

```
public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

You can put any field in the Auth::attempt() method.

```
$credentials = [
        'username' => $request->input('username'),
        'password' => $request->input('password'),
    ];
Auth::attempt($credentials)
```

: this will select the user with this username then check if the password match.